# Raycast or timing or lag?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So i'm running a test on a raycast physics handler from a tutorial. I am dropping a block from the same height each simulation with the goal to have the block land on top of a flat surface in one smooth motion. Currently, I have raycasts projecting out of the bottom of the box through a skin width with the raylength scaling off the `velocity.y` as seen below:

```
rayOrigin += Vector2.right * (verticalRaySpacing * i + velocity.x);
//Sends out the ray at its respective spot an length

RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, Vector2.up * directionY, rayLength, collisionMask);
Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin, Vector2.up * directionY * rayLength, Color.red);

//If the ray hits, make velocity = distance to the hit distance - skin width
//Also reset the rayLength for edge height discrepencies
if (hit)
{
    //Reports the very first hit.distance and velocity.y at the first hit
    if (!temp && hit.distance != 0)
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.distance);
        Debug.Log(velocity.y);
        temp = true;
    }

    velocity.y = (hit.distance - skinWidth) * directionY;
    rayLength = hit.distance;
}
```

My problem is that when i run this simulation over and over, about half the time when the block collides with the flat surface it produces this initial "stopping force" a bit above the surface, and then the gravity on the block restarts and pulls it directly onto the surface.

So basically, sometimes it is sensing a collision at higher distances than other times forcing it to stop mid-air too early. I have mapped this out by watching the `Debug.Log` on the `hit.distance` and `velocity.y`. The times where this unfavorable effect happens, the `hit.distance` is above `0.1` and the `velocity.y` is about `-9.56`, while the times that are favorable the `hit.distance` is somewhere below `0.1` and the `velocity.y` is `-9.67`.

What is causing this difference in the simulation heights and numbers when i am not changing the system at all? Is it lag in the editor or something that needs to be accounted for? Will it show up on a mobile App?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you running this in `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`?

Comment: Are you multiplying the ray lengths by `time.deltaTime`?

Comment: @moonismadeofcheese here is what i am using to calculate raylength         "float rayLength = Mathf.Abs(velocity.y * Time.deltaTime) + skinWidth;" (also thank you for answering my question the other day as well)

Comment: @Draco18s I am running these in Update(). I think you are onto something that I overlooked though. All my physics movements should've been in FixedUpdate() correct? This leads me to believe the inconsistencies in the update's time.deltaTime is the culprit of what I am seeing

Comment: @Draco18s It turns out you analyzed the situation correctly. I foolishly had my physics placed in the Update() function instead of FIxedUpdate() function and the variation in time.deltaTIme caused the inconsistent raycasting issues. My mistake. You should respond as a full answer and i'd be happy to check it as the correct answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments confirmed, my suspicion was true:

You are running this code in `Update()` not `FixedUpdate()` and therefore it isn't synchronized with the physics engine. The discrepancy (at a sub-update interval) caused the Update loop's code to execute early, imparting too much force, so by the time the physics simulation ran (on FixedUpdate's schedule) the object was still too high and gravity took over once more.

The only solution is to move your code to `FixedUpdate()`